# Appveyor not building, since reference is missing

Tags: c#, reference, appveyor

I have a project, that has an external API reference which my code is calling. The API itself does not, and cannot reside inside my Program folder, thus copying the required dll is out of the question.

However this makes appveyor not build my Project at all, since the required dll is (obviously) missing. Here is the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PCompiler". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\projects\skyrimcompilehelper\Compiler\Compiler.csproj]
CompilerFactory.cs(25,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PCompiler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\projects\skyrimcompilehelper\Compiler\Compiler.csproj]
CompilerFactory.cs(277,64): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompilerNotifyEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\projects\skyrimcompilehelper\Compiler\Compiler.csproj]
CompilerFactory.cs(293,68): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompilerErrorEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\projects\skyrimcompilehelper\Compiler\Compiler.csproj]
Command exited with code 1
```

Is there a way to change this, or do I have to include the required DLLs in my project folder?

Comment: It needs to be from a NuGet package, or in your project folder, or anyway downloadable from Internet, so that you can configure AppVoyer to get the reference recovered before compilation.

Comment: Damn. The API is not available on the internet, and because of license reasons I cannot upload it. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why cannot you use a private repository? It is accessible from Internet but strictly protected and should not violate the licensing in most cases. If the licensing is so strict, you probably are not supposed to use AppVoyer either, as that file will appear anyway on a virtual machine owned by AppVoyer, not yours.

Comment: My project is OpenSource and I want it to stay that way. The API I use just forbids redistribution. The API file itself is not in my repository, but contains just a reference to it and thus is not uploaded to AppVeyor. I just want to know if there is a possibility to fix the error, without uploading the file, the API is contained in.

Comment: If the API dlls is not signed, you can easily create a mock to replace it in compilation. If it is signed, it would be more difficult to do so. Instead of using AppVoyer, you probably should build a private Jenkins server in this case if you cannot get rid of this dll.

Comment: The DLL is not signed, so creating a mock would be an option. Thanks.